# Плагин на сайт. Как импортировать контактные данные сразу в телефонную книгу?

Tags: веб-программирование, импорт, контакты

Требуется сайт визитка для конкретного человека, с данными полностью для телефонной книги, то есть локация, место работы и все остальное не говоря уже о ФИО и номере телефона, есть возможность все эти данные сохранить на телефон человека одним кликом?

Comment: Создайте обычную ссылку на файл с контактом (vCard) — в зависимости от операционной системы, нативными средствами будет предложен импорт контакта.

Comment: Спасибо, хотя бы понял куда двигаться, я просто как плагин искал возможность на сайт шаблонку (типа WIX) прицепить, так как впринципе не программист, теперь попробую еще подумать как это сделать)